# Не запускается скомпилированный файл exe

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Делаю программу в electron и пытаюсь экспортировать в файл exe. По какой-то причине команда

```
npm run start
```

нормально запускает приложение и оно корректно работает. Далее пытаюсь экспортировать в exe и файл exe нормально формируется. Но вот при запуске скомпилированного приложения отображается просто пустое окно... Никакой отрисовки вообще не происходит. Может подскажете, как мне экспортировать в exe?

Компилирую через команду

```
npm run package-win
```

Код package.json ниже

```json
{
  "name": "game",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . game --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"proxy-tester\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "GUA",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^16.0.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-machine-id": "latest"
  }
}
```

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества, пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную претензию или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно

Comment: А что выводит в консоле при компиляции?